# git pull origin master, check if any conflicts without pull

Tags: git, jenkins, build, jenkins-groovy

I want to automate a build where before creating the build i have to pull from master and then I have to build the package. But I want to have a check point to see if there is any conflict before pulling from master so that I can make the build to fail.

Can anyone please advise how to do it in gitscm for jenkins(or git also fine). I am not able to find a proper solution, maybe my understanding is not clear since i am not having development background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a copy of the destination branch, try to pull on it, then depending on the exit code you'll know if you can make the same on the real destination. It sure feels like there would/should be a more "elegant" way to preemptively know, but I'm not aware of one.

Comment: Yes, It worked in the same way as shell script but i thought there must be a way in git command itself. Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that `pull` means *run `fetch`, then run a second command to do something with commits obtained by `fetch`*. That *second* command is *configurable* and is the one that may or may not have merge conflicts. If you're building software that's meant to be predictable and reliable, *do not use `git pull` here* because `git pull` acts based on some user's configuration, which makes it hard to predict.

Comment: In any case, the only way to tell if a merge—assuming you want `git merge` as the second command—is going to fail is to *attempt* it. Currently that means you must *try it in the working tree*. There's only that one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this work in jenkins, the build job would be working on its own sandbox, which you can destructively used since it's temporary anyway. All you need to do is check the exit status from the `git pull` operation, as @Romain Valeri suggests, and proceed only on success, since a git pull with a conflict exits with non-zero.

If your recipe was in bash, something like this would work:

```sh
if git pull; then
   # proceed with build
else
   # there was a conflict, abort with error
fi
```

or just

```
git pull or exit_with_error
# proceed with build
```

The equivalent should be simple to do in your jenkins build recipe.

Comment: Yes, It worked in the same way as shell script but i thought there must be a way in git command itself. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, whether in git command, in a shell or in a recipe, it's still going to boil down to acting on the exit code from the pull operation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're looking for is the command fetch, which does almost the same thing as pull and can give you the opportunity to check the conflicts.

Comment: I think OP wanted to know *programmatically* if a pull will provoke conflicts. How will fetching achieve this?